# How to create a static array that has a length defined by user input?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, static

I have a program where a number of grades are entered by the user and stored into array which is then used by the program to calculate various values.

I'm using multiple methods so I want to define a static array that all the methods can refer to and will hold the grades. However I want its length to be equal to the number of grades entered.

```
public class GradeStatistics {
static int numGrades, sum = 0;
static int[] grades = new int[numGrades];

public static void main(String args[]){
    readGrades();
    calcSum();
```

the `readGrades()` method finds out how many grades there will be and assigns it to numGrades

```
public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
    numGrades = input.nextInt();
```

Is there a way I can get the user to enter the number of grades before defining the static array?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using an array and not an arraylist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the static array, but not initialize it:

```
static int[] grades;
```

Then you can call the `readGrades()` method and initialize the `grades` array inside it:

```
public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
    numGrades = input.nextInt();
    grades = new int[numGrades];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not forced to *initialize* a field when *declaring* it. The initialization can come after, and the variable can be reinitialized any number of times. So you just need

```
static int[] grades; // declaration. The field is implicitely initialized to null.

public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
    int numGrades = input.nextInt();
    grades = new int[numGrades]; // initialization
```

Note that I made `numGrades` a local  variable rather than a static field. There is no reason to make it a static field. The number of grades is available using `grades.length`.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the grades array you don't have to assign it.

```
static int[] grades;
```

And then just assign it when you're reading in the nr of grades.

```
public static void readGrades(){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
numGrades = input.nextInt();
grades = new int[numGrades];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the `readGrades` method like this

```
public static int[] readGrades(){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
   numGrades = input.nextInt();
   int[] grades = new int[numGrades];
   // read the grades
   return grades;
}
```

since it is more intuitive and encapsulated if a method that is named `readGrades` also returns something.

Answer (score 0):

you may init the array int your static method : readGrades

like this:

```
public class GradeStatistics {
  static int numGrades, sum = 0;
  static int[] grades = null;

public static void main(String args[]){
  readGrades();
  calcSum();
}


 public static void readGrades(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of grades: ");
    numGrades = input.nextInt();
    grades = new int[numGrades];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare you grades like this

```
static int[] grades = null;
```

And initialize the grades like below.

```
public static void readGrades(){

       numGrades = input.nextInt();
       grades  =new int[numGrades];
}
```